# Show that the the given sequence doesn't converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Show that the sequence defined by $u_{1} = \frac{1}{3}, u_{2n} = \frac{1}{3} u_{2n-1}, u_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{3} + u_{2n}$ for all $n≥1$  is not convergent.

Since $u_{2n+4} - u_{2n+2} = \frac{1}{3}( u_{2n+2} - u_{2n})$ and $u_{2n+3} - u_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{3}( u_{2n+1} - u_{2n-1})$

So both subsequences are convergent.
I need to show that both converge to different limits. How can I find the limits of these subsequences$?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that the subsequences $u_{2n}$ and $u_{2n+1}$ are convergent from the equality you found. Let their limits be $E$ and $O$ respectively.

Then, we get :
$$
u_{2n} = \frac{1}{3} u_{2n-1} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} E = \frac O3\\
u_{2n+1} = \frac 13 + u_{2n} \xrightarrow{n \to\infty} O = \frac 13 + E
$$

solving this pair of simultaneous equations gives us $E = \frac 16 , O = \frac 12$. So of course the sequence is not convergent as $E \neq O$.

Answer (score 1):

Write out recurrence for each sequence to compute their limit,

> $$u_{2n+2}=\frac{1}{3} * u_{2n+1}= \frac{1}{3} (\frac{1}{3}+u_{2n})$$. 
>  $$u_{2n+3}=\frac{1}{3} + u_{2n+2}= \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3} * (u_{2n+1})$$, hence have different limit.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it converges. Consider two subseries: $x_n = u_{2n}$ and $y_n=u_{2n+1}$.

Based on Heine's definition of limit both must converge and have the same limit for $u_n$ to converge. Let's assign $L=\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$., But also $y_n=x_n+\frac{1}{3}$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty}y_n \neq L$.

Answer (score 0):

If it converges to a finite limit, then $u_{2n+1}-u_{2n} = \frac{1}{3}$ converges to $0$.

Apparently $\frac{1}{3} \not\to 0$